# ASP.NET Core 2.x - Proxy Service Provider

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to build a DI proxy for ASP.NET Core 2.x apps. My understanding is that you do that by returning **IServiceProvider** instance in the ConfigureServices method e.g.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    return new ProxyServiceProvider(services);
}
```

Below is an example of the proxy.

```
internal class ProxyServiceProvider : IServiceProvider, ISupportRequiredService
{
    private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

    public ProxyServiceProvider(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public object GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == typeof(IValuesService))
        {
            return new ValuesService();
        }

        return ServiceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

This implementation works fine for services registered through the service collection, but surprisingly the framework never calls GetService for IValuesService.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromServices]IValuesService service)
{
    return service.GetAll();
}
```

The code above then throws an unhandled exception when it tries to create an instance of ValuesController.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder+<BindModelAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
...
```

If I register the service via `services.AddScoped<IValuesService, ValuesService>()` an instance gets resolved, but the GetService method on my proxy is completely bypassed.

It looks like something else controls the instance resolution. What am I missing here?

Comment: You posted a bit of the stack trace, but what's the actual exception and message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

```
services.addsingleton<Ivalueservices, valueservices>
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the original post, AddScoped/Singleton works, but I’d like to understand why GetService is bypassed and how does an instance get created then?